# How to transport code, not material, with a float?

Tags: floats, patching

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}%

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{tikzducks}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage{color}%


\begin{document}
    \color{red}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{A duck}
    \end{figure}
    \let\endfigureold\endfigure%
    \renewcommand\endfigure{\textbf{Trying to change color here}\global\color{green}\endfigureold}%
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{Another duck}
%        \textbf{Trying to change color here}\global\color{green}%
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

What I try to accomplish:
I have two figures on consecutive pages. I want the text to be red from the beginning till the second figure, after the second figure it should be green.

You can see two attempts of mine up to now: First I tried to write the command for changing the color inside the figure environment directly under the caption. On a second try, I patched the end of the figure environment. In both cases, the text remains completely red.

Further, I wrote `\textbf{Trying to change color here}` directly near my attempt to change the color. In both cases, this text appears just under the caption.

It seems, that I easily can transport "material" with a float. But it seems impossible to transport "information". The best, I could accomplish by further attempts with a non-minimum-file, e.g. by changing a flag, was that the change took place at the very point, where the figure appears in the source, i.e. the complete text became green, and no red remained.

It seems to me, that the complete code of the figure is evaluated at the very place in the source, where I write it, if "information" can escape the environment, it does it here, only the "material" becomes transported. Am I right?

And, in the moment more important to me, is there any chance to achieve, what I want -- that is not in the first line the color, only serving as an example here, but generally information, that starts to work at the very point of a figure, e.g. stepping up of a counter?

Comment: Floats consist of `\savebox`es which are stored in a queue (`\@deferlist` etc.).  They are formatted immediately, although aux fiile IO is delayed until the savebox is used (SOP for all saveboxes).  If you want to save information, you need to use the aux file.

Comment: this can not be made to work in any reasonable way. floats are typeset when saved and added, like page headings after all page content is set

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to change the color on the page where the float will appear. The only problem is that LaTeX reverts that again in the output routine by calling `\normalcolor`. If one disables that (not recommended!) you get a green page (but only one as you can't change the color stack).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum,color}%
\begin{document}

\let\normalcolor\relax %avoid that it interferes

before

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{A duck}  
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
   \caption{Another duck} 
   \pdfliteral {0 1 0 RG 0 1 0 rg}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It is also possible to do other things on pages with floats. The following e.g rotates the page. With lualatex it makes use of `\latelua` and works in one compilation. pdflatex records the page to rotate in the aux-file and then rotates it on the next compilation (it could probably do it in one compilation too on a current system with the new shipout keyword, but I hadn't time yet to look).

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum,color}%
\begin{document}

before

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{A duck}  
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
   \caption{Another duck} 
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \pdfmanagement_add:nnn{ThisPage}{Rotate}{90}
   \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

You can also step a counter on the page of the float. But be aware that this is done in the shipout and so the counter is only reliable in the shipout too, e.g. in the footer or header. If you need it in other places uses label + ref.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum,color,zref-abspage,zref-user}%
\newcounter{myfloat}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/before}
{\ifnum \numexpr\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+2\relax =\zref@extractdefault{blub}{abspage}{-1} 
 \stepcounter{myfloat}\fi}
 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{myfloat counter:  \themyfloat}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{A duck}  
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
   \caption{Another duck} 
  \zlabel{blub}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ulrike, that is a quite interesting answer, as it helps me to understand LaTeX a bit better (that was, why I asked more generalized).

Although there seem to be only specialized solutions for special problems, your last example gave me a chance to solve my original problem: With the line \lhead{\ifnum\value{myfloat}=1\relax\addtocounter{myfloat}{-1}\else This is just a header\fi} I can switch off \lhead just on the one page with the float.

Comment: Do not forget to consider the case that two floats end on a page ...

Comment: Thank you for the hint -- I surely would have forgotten. But in my very special case fortunately that is no problem ...