# How to insert a figure while inside a large breakable tcolorbox

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

The breakable boxes made by `tcolorbox` play nicely with figures that have been defined before the box but have not been typeset yet. Here's an example:

[image: screenshot]

The three figures have been issued before the yellow box began, and have no problem appearing on the first page of the breakable box or the page after that.

My problem is that I have some figures that I want to appear later throughout a multi-page breakable box, so I want to issue them somewhere throughout a box. This does not work – any attempt to define figure inside a `tcolorbox` gives this error:

> Not in outer par mode.

I tried to work around that by wrapping the figure into an `\afterpage`, to make sure it is processed outside of the `tcolorbox` context, but this didn't help at all.

Is there any way to insert a figure while a breakable `tcolorbox` is open so they are typeset at a controllable later point throught the box?

---

To put things into a minimal example: The questions is how to get something like this working:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering\Huge
    This is a figure.
    \caption{A figure that will work}
\end{figure}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    \lipsum[1-20]

    \begin{figure}
        \centering\Huge
        This is a figure.
        \caption{A figure that will not work}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[21-30]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not use `begin{figure}`, just `\include`  and\cptionof` for the captions.

Comment: That would simply place the contents of the figure and add a caption line, not let the figure float to the best top or bottom position, right? Also note that I don't want the figure to be rendered inside the box – the screenshot in the question shows how I want this to look, just with the ability to also have figures like this later throughout the box.

Comment: A figure in a box is like a bird in a cage. He can not  fly.

Comment: Thanks I see. No you cannot achieve it with tcolorbox. It cannot break at a page, then break to insert an image and then restart again.

Comment: Well it can… if the figure is already in the list of to-be-typeset floats. I just can't add a new figure to this list…
It feels like the hard part already works and the easy part is impossible.

Comment: It might be possible to create a figure insert and add it to `\@deferlist` without using the float environment.  Get an insert from `\@freelist`,  put the figure into the box register, the bit flags into the count register and the total height into the length register.  OTOH, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689529/how-to-let-a-figure-appear-exactly-on-page-16

Comment: People are more likely to play with this if you provide the code for them to play.

Comment: If the background color plus frame is a global feature of the document text, then you can re-define the `\output` routine which will do this background decoration with `\box255`. The floats (i.e. `\insert`s from TeX primitive point of view) will work in this case.

Comment: @cfr I added a MWE above.

Comment: @wipet The frame I want to use is more complicated than that, unfortunately.

Comment: @fefrei Regardless of the complexity of decoration it is possible to do it at `\output` routine level, if you want to have floats (i.e. `\insert`s) inside decorated text.

Comment: @wipet I think the OP wants the floats outside the decorated text. So the background and frame aren't supposed to apply to the floats.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, you can use the `shipout` hook to insert some material at the top of the next page, and mimic a figure environment (the `caption` package provides the `\captionof` command to display a caption outside a float).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof command

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering\Huge
    This is a figure.
    \caption{A figure that will work}
\end{figure}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    \lipsum[1-20]

    \AddToHookNext{shipout}{
      \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
        \centering\Huge
        This is a figure.
        \captionof{figure}{A figure that will not work}
      \end{minipage}
      \bigskip
    }

    \lipsum[21-30]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

But it's not a real float, as you required.